# The React variable changes, but it is not rendered... why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a newby in React, and I have a problem with the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import banner from './images/banner.png';
import logo from './images/logo.png';
import coin from './images/coin.png';
import './App.css';
var $ = require('jquery');


function CardItem(props) {
  return (
                    <li>
                        <div className="imageWrapper">
                            <img/>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>Category</p>

                    </li>
  );
}


class Cards extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    let items = [];
    this.items = items;

     $.ajax({
      url: '//localhost:3004/products',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {

       items.push(data);

      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
         console.log("\nError:" + err);

      }
    });
  }

    render(){


        var itemsList = this.items.map(function(oneItem){

            return <CardItem/>;
        });



        return (

                <section>
                    <h2>{this.items.length} Products</h2>

                    <ul>
                {itemsList}     

                    </ul>
                </section>
        );
    }
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (


        <div className="App">
            <header>
                <img className="logo" src={logo}/>
                <img className="banner" src={banner}/>


            </header>

            <Cards/>

        </div>


    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

It's supposed the web browser should show the list of the array `items`, but instead of that it shows nothing, just like the array was empty.

When the callback changes the variable `items`, what I see in the browser doesn't update. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: dont use Jquery AJax...use some npm package like request or aXIOS

Comment: All the ajax calls are to be made in componentDidMount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems that I see:

1. `items.push(data)` will actually append the array of products as an item to your `items` array. Use `this.items = this.items.concat(data)` instead.
2. You need to re-render your component when data is received. So I would better keep your items in the component state: call `this.setState({ items: data })` in success callback (that will trigger re-rendering) and use `this.state.items` in the `render()` method instead of `this.items`

And as Rohitas said, do your AJAX requests in `componentDidMount`

So your `Cards` component could be something like:

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';

// ...

class Cards extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('//localhost:3004/products')
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status >= 400) {
          console.error('Unable to fetch products', res);
        } else {
          res.json()
            .then(items => this.setState({ items });
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <h2>{this.state.items.length} Products</h2>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item =>
            <CardItem {...item} />)}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry! Thank you for your help! I'm not sure, but I think I am doing something wrong, because I get this error in the browser: 

`TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function
Cards.render
src/App.js:119
  116 | <section>
  117 |   <h2>{this.state.items} Products</h2>
  118 |   <ul>
> 119 |     {this.state.items.map(item =>
  120 |       <CardItem {...item} />)}
  121 |   </ul>
  122 | </section>`

Comment: @Captain `res.json()` returned Promise. I've just fixed the example. Also make sure that your `/products` endpoint returns list, otherwise you will also need an additional step to extract the list from the returned data

Comment: PERFECT! It worked! Thank you very much, @Dmitry . Your help is very valuable!